# InvalidCastException inside MonoTouch's AVFoundation.AVAsset.FromUrl

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, avfoundation

I'm trying a very simple program: load a resource video using AVFoundation, and get the video frame bytes as an OpenGL texture.

The general flow is quite straightforward:

- I load the video into an `AVAsset`
- Then I get the video track into an `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`
- I plug it into an `AVAssetReader`
- I start reading
- And for each video frame, I get a `CMSampleBuffer`, from which I get a `CVPixelBuffer`.
- I then lock the `CVPixelBuffer`, and upload this into OpenGL with `GL.TexImage2D`

It works pretty well in the emulator, but when I try it in an actual device, I'm getting the following error in the first step:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVAsset.FromUrl (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl url) [0x00011] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/AVFoundation/AVAsset.g.cs:231
  at MyTestApp.EAGLView.LoadVideo () [0x00033] in /Volumes/Shared/MyTestApp/MyTestApp/EAGLView.cs:191
```

The code that throws the exception goes like:

```
private AVAsset videoAsset;
private AVAssetReaderTrackOutput videoReaderOutput;
private AVAssetReader videoReader;

private void LoadVideo()
{
    var videoPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("video", "mp4");
    var videoURL = NSUrl.FromFilename(videoPath);
    Console.WriteLine ("Loading from " + videoURL.ToString ());
    object videoAssetRaw = AVAsset.FromUrl(videoURL); // Exception thrown here
    videoAsset = videoAssetRaw as AVAsset;
    var tracks = videoAsset.Tracks;
    NSError error;
    AVAssetTrack videoTrack = tracks[0];

    AVVideoSettings settings = new AVVideoSettings ();
    settings.PixelFormat = CVPixelFormatType.CV32BGRA;

    videoReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput.FromTrack(videoTrack, settings.ToDictionary());
    videoReader = new AVAssetReader (videoAsset, out error);
    videoReader.AddOutput (videoReaderOutput);
    videoReader.StartReading ();
}
```

I got it into an `object` instead of the `AVAsset` directly, just to make sure that the `InvalidCastException` is not being thrown on my side, but as the exception reads, it is being thrown on line 231 of `AVAsset.g.cs`, which I don't have.

The video file is being built as a "BundleResource", and I'm using the latest version of xamarin (downloaded earlier today).

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: Can you test the existence of your file (on the device) ? prior to calling `Assert.FromUrl`.

Comment: @poupou That's going to have to wait until tomorrow. However, if the file were not there, shouldn't I be getting a `FileNotFoundException`, or at least some kind of `IOExcepton`?

Comment: No, you're calling **native** code so you won't get a managed exception from it. In general Apple API returns `null` in such condition. If the file exists then I suggest you to file a bug report (with a self-contained test case) so we can look into it (and see what's being returned, it would mean it's not an `AVAsset` subclass like documented).

Comment: @poupou: But I _am_ getting a managed exception, an `InvalidCastException`. One which gets thrown inside the xamarin API. If indeed I were getting a `null` as you say, I would be getting a `NullReferenceException` when I try to use the returned value, but that is not the case. In other words, the one who is doing an invalid cast is the xamarin API (to be exact, `AVAsset.FromUrl`), not me.

Comment: What *might* happen is that Apple does not return an `AVAsset` (nor `null`) like **documented** in case of an error (or for your specific asset). That would throw an `InvalidCastException` in the binding code. You can easily confirm about the non-existing vs `null` condition. If it exists then we'll need a test case so we can see what type of object is being returned.

Comment: @poupou: Well, I tried with a different filename, to see what happens when I'm positive the file doesn't exist. This time, `PathForResource()` returns `null`, and therefore `NSUrl.FromFilename()` fails with an `ArgumentNullException`. If I call `NSUrl.FromFilename()` with a hardcoded incorrect path, I get a non-null empty `AVAsset`. I got it working by setting the build action to "Content" instead of "BundleResource", so the file itself _can_ be read and interpreted correctly by `AVAsset.FromUrl()`. The problem is still there, but I have my workaround. Are you still interested in a bug report?

Comment: Yes, please. You might also want to answer your own question here, with your workaround (it's ok to answer it's own questions on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of ...

```
object videoAssetRaw = AVAsset.FromUrl(videoURL);
```

Try ...

```
AVUrlAssetOptions options = null;
var asset = new AVUrlAsset (url, options);
```